# Ambiguity of PEG grammar with PEST parser

Tags: rust, peg

I'm trying to write a PEG for an old file format that has about 100 keywords which can't be used as identifiers.

Here's an example of a keyword rule:

```
IN = { ^"in" } // Caret means case insensitivity

keyword = { IN } // plus others
```

The identifier rule looks like this:

```
identifier = @{ ( "_" | ASCII_ALPHA ) ~ ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC* }
```

Currently this identifier rule will match all the keywords. So the identifier rule becomes:

```
identifier = @{ !keyword ~ ( "_" | ASCII_ALPHA ) ~ ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC* }
```

This kind of works, except when an identifier begins with the same letters as a keyword. For example, the identifier `inner` is treated as the keyword `in` followed by text.

How to allow identifiers that begin with keywords? Note that in the PEST parser generator, terminals can only be specified as strings, not regex.

Comment: Can't you define `keyword` as `{ IN &space }`?

Answer (score 4):

You can force `keyword` to only match full words by using a [predicate](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#predicates).  For example:

```
identifier_start = _{ "_" | ASCII_ALPHA }
identifier_continue = _{ "_" | ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC }

keyword = @{ (^"for" | ^"in") ~ !identifier_continue }
identifier = @{ !keyword ~ identifier_start ~ identifier_continue* ~ !identifier_continue }
```

This will match `for` and `in`, but not `form` or `int`.